Code Coverage For Android Integration Tests In Multi-Module App
I am looking for some help generating a code coverage report for Android integration tests in a multi-module project. Specifically I have an app module along with a mix of android and java library modules with various features and utilities. In this case all the tests these within the androidTest dir of the app module while testing code from the various feature modules. Sample module layout is as follows:
--app
--feature-module1 //android module
--feature-module2 //android module
--util-module //java module

I am able to generate the coverage report for the app module, but this only contains coverage for code within the app module itself, and I only see .ec files generated for this module. There are many blog posts(here, here) around combining coverage files in addition to some Stackoverflow posts(here). All eventually seem to link to this sample project here. Unfortunately, these samples all have the tests live within the various modules near the code instead of singularly in the main app module. Therefore, the solutions do not work as .ec and coverage files are not generated and therefore cannot be combined. These only generate the code cov file for the app module in my case.
This issue is the closest thing I can find but does not appear to really be solved and like most of the other posts, is pretty dated. Im hoping anyone has a more up to date way to approach this! Or at least can let me know if this is not possible.
